# Python App Engine Full Text Search > empty search return all documents of a search.Index

Tags: python, google-app-engine, full-text-search

I am trying to mimic the normal behavior of an empty search on a collection. Usually and empty search should returns all entities. How can i do this with App Engines Full Text Search? Basically how do i return all documents in a given index without any search params?

The reason i can't just return the Datastore collection in this case is the Models have parents and this search is a global search not based on any of the ancestors.

As always thanks for any help with this.

Comment: You have to iterate around each document in turn, as per the delete example. Only 10k results can be returned for a search in any case, so you can't return all anyway.

Comment: Thats sad, thanks for the answer though. To delete the method is `doc_index.delete`. What is the get method?

Comment: get or get_range. And you get the ID's by iterating around the index, as the delete example demonstrates. You'd just do something other then "delete".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instance (untested and very not optimum):

```
from google.appengine.api import search
...
def get_all_in_index(index_name):
    """Get all the docs in the given index."""
    results = []
    doc_index = search.Index(name=index_name)

    # looping because get_range by default returns up to 100 documents at a time
    while True:
        # Get a list of documents populating only the doc_id field and extract the ids.
        document_ids = [document.doc_id
                        for document in doc_index.get_range(ids_only=True)]
        if not document_ids:
            break
        # Get the documents for the given ids from the Index.
        results.append(doc_index.get_range(document_ids))
```

Comment: `get_range`, thats the one. Thanks again. I wonder why they don't have a empty search default which i think is standard practice. Maybe that is an incorrect assumption.

Comment: It is an incorrect assumption.  The way the indexes work, it only indexes entities with a value for the particular index. So there is nothing to match with an empty query.